# Printing on a inkjet printer EPSON ET-3850 series, only the last document in queue gets printed

Tags: printing, epson, cups-lpd

I have a EPSON ET-3850 with CUPS automatic driverless setup (v2.0rc1) in Ubuntu 23.04 (standard CUPS installation).

Whenever I try to print more than one file, only the last one gets printed -- all the earlier ones disappear. This is consistent behavior. This prohibits me from using `lp file*` or similar to print out a couple of files at the same time.

Error message from `/var/log/cups/error_log` is

```
E [16/Aug/2023:20:42:54 +0200] [Job 209] Druckauftrag wurde am Drucker abgebrochen.
W [16/Aug/2023:20:42:54 +0200] [Job 209] Backend dnssd returned status 5 (cancel job)
```

*Translation of line #1: print job was canceled at the printer*

`lpstat -t` doesn't show anything off.

Is there anything I can do to correct this from the Ubuntu (PC) side?

It is **not** an issue of the printer hardware, because I can print multiple documents with the old, soon-to-be deprecated Epson ESC/P-R driver for CUPS.

Comment: Look at the logs in `/var/log/cups/*`. See the current state of your printing system with `lpstat -t`. Manage your printing system by browsing to `http://localhost:631`